# Power BI - Calculation using the same column based on other rows in table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, dashboard, measure

I am working on a Power BI dashboard, trying to display a calculation which is 'Value - Spend' (in this example it should bring back 5000 for product A, 3000 for B).

However I am struggling to set this up in Power BI due to the calculation all being done in the Values column, with specific filters depending on what product is on that row.

Is there a way to do this? Any help would be massively appreciated.

Currently -

```
|Product|Values|Outcomes|
|A      |Value |20000   |
|A      |Spend |15000   |
|B      |Value |10000   |
|B      |Spend |7000    |
```

Ideal solution -

```
|Product|Values|Outcomes|
|A      |Value |20000   |
|A      |Spend |15000   |
|A      |Return|5000    |
|B      |Value |10000   |
|B      |Spend |7000    |
|A      |Return|3000    |
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a solution how to add new rows for your table, however you can create measures in the dashboard.

If you try to create a measure, than here is my code for you:

```
Measure_value = calculate(sum(Outcomes),
filter(all(Table),
and(selectedvalue(Table[Values]) = "Value")
selectedvalue(Table[Product]) = Table[Product]
))

Measure_spend = calculate(sum(Outcomes),
filter(all(Table),
and(selectedvalue(Table[Values]) = "Spend")
selectedvalue(Table[Product]) = Table[Product]
))

Measure_calc = Measure_value - Measure_spend
```

Please, let me know if it helps